# PHP Headers for downloading a file on IIS

Tags: php, iis

I have a php script that uses header tags to download a remote file from a CDN to the user's machine.  I am doing it this way to mask the real URL from where the file is coming.  This is my code, where $file is the real URL to the file.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);

$filesize = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
curl_close($ch);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

I had this set up on a linux machine and it was working fine.  I moved this over to a windows box running IIS and now I am getting a lot of complaints of interrupted downloads and downloads not completing.  Is it something with my code or with IIS or with my php configuration that is causing the issue?

Comment: Is the php config even the same on both boxes ? If the files are big or take too long to fetch, you might be going over `max_execution_time`. You could also run out of memory. There are way too many possibilities here.

Comment: @spenibus it is a 1.5GB file and the max_execution_time is set to 999999999 so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I imagine IIS has logs, maybe there is a clue somewhere in there. Also: http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/troubleshoot-my-php-script-is-timing-out

Comment: here is a copy of my php.ini

http://pastebin.com/Axgs0QRk

Comment: There's too much ground to cover really. Looking through server logs (both iis and php) would be a better starting point.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the IIS logs except 200 calls to the urls and nothing in the php error logs except some notices about some undefined variables left in my code.  nothing in the event viewer either.

Comment: I turned on failed request tracing and it looks like I am getting FASTCGI_REQUEST_TIMEOUT at around the 15 minute mark of downloading

Comment: Well, now you have a venue to explore. Seems my previous link might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was.  It was a setting on FastCGI.  To solve I went into IIS Manager, clicked on the server then opened "FastCGI Settings". For anyone else who experiences this:

Right click on the executable and select "edit" and change the "Activity Timeout" setting from "600" (10 minutes) to another value that will allow the download to complete (I put "60000").  Make the same change for "Request Timeout".  Save your settings and you should be good to go.